# Android PayPal SDK: What does EXTRA_PAYER_ID do?

Tags: android, paypal, in-app-purchase

I have implemented Paypal IAP via the PayPal's Android SDK and live payments go through fine. I need a way to link the IAP transaction to the PayPal's web console and I believe `PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYER_ID` is designed for that purpose.

I set this ID to be something that uniquely identifies the user on the system but I'm unable to find this value anywhere on Paypal's admin console (which I need if I'm to find the transaction to make a refund etc).

The code that sets this value is pretty simple:

```
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_CLIENT_ID,
            <API_KEY>);

    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYER_ID,
            <USER_UNIQUE_ID>);

    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, thingToBuy);

    startActivityForResult(intent,
            1123);
```

Am I missing something important to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the unique identifier to remember credit card or PayPal login information from paypal.

Comment: Jeff from PayPal here.  Just to add, this unique identifier is used only on the device, and will not be available anywhere on any PayPal servers.  In short, this id is used to remember credit card and login info, and nothing else.